# gnu parallel exit process with timeout

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

Is it possible to abort process for gnu parallel process if it exceeds an estimated runtime? For example, I have a handler for recon-all processing:

```
while [ -n "${ids[0]}" ] ; do
printf 'Processing ID: %s\n' "${ids[@]}" >&2

    /usr/bin/time -f "$timefmt" \
    printf '%s\n' "${ids[@]}" | parallel --jobs 0 recon-all -s {.} -all - 
    qcache -parallel -openmp 8

    n=$(( n + 1 ))
    ids=( "${all_ids[@]:n*4:4}" ) # pick out the next eight IDs
done
```

and some patients in recon-all process inside parallel couldn't be completed for some reasons (could run several days, which abnormal).
Could I limit the runtime inside parallel for 9 hours, so the command will run another group in the cycle?

Comment: Not really sure why you want to run in batches of 8. Why not just use -j8 and run all ids with 8 running constantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for  `--timeout`.

You can do `--timeout 9h` or you can do `--timeout 1000%`. The last will measure how long the median time is for a job to succeed, and given the median it will compute a timeout that is 1000% of the median run time.

The neat thing about using a percentage is that if the compute program gets faster or slower for the normal case, you will not need to change the timeout.

See it in action:

```
parallel --timeout 300% 'sleep {}; echo {}' ::: 100 2 3 1 50  2 3 1 2 1 3 2 1 4 2 1 2 3
# Compute program gets 10 times faster
parallel --timeout 300% 'sleep {=$_ /= 10 =}; echo {}' ::: 100 2 3 1 50  2 3 1 2 1 3 2 1 4 2 1 2 3
```

The median (not average) runtime is measured as the median of the succesfully completed jobs (though minimum 3). So if you have 8 jobs with job 5 being infinite, it will get killed when the runtime hits the percentage of the median timeout:

```
parallel --timeout 300% 'sleep {}; echo {}' ::: 1 2 1 2 100 2 1 2
```

This also works if the first job is the one that is stuck:

```
parallel --timeout 300% 'sleep {}; echo {}' ::: 100 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
```

The only situation it does not work is if all jobslots are stuck on their first job:

```
parallel -j4 --timeout 300% 'sleep {}; echo {}' ::: 100 100 100 100 1 2 1 2
```

Comment: The problem is that issues can occur on first pack of patients, so 7 of 8 done, but e.g 5th have infinite runtime (because it stuck at "CORRECTING DEFECT 5  for example), so the parallel can't measure average processing time to --timeout with %

Comment: In most cases it can. See edit.

Comment: gnu parallel doesn't work with 9h right? you should write it in seconds? 6000?

Comment: Of course it works with 9h.

Comment: I tried with --timeout 11h flag. And it except an error as unknown argument

Comment: Are you using version 20190222?

Comment: No my version is 20161222. Switch ot 20190222?